# Java get size of inner ArrayList

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

```
static ArrayList<String> tableNamesMD = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> columnNamesMD = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

After both arrays are populated

```
for(int i = 0; i < tableNamesMD.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(tableNamesMD.get(i));

        for(int j = 0; j < tableNamesMD.get(i).size(); j++) {
            //do stuff here
        }
}
```

There is an error with the inner for loop at the tableNamesMD.get(i).size()

It's say "The method size() is undefined for the type String"

Comment: Use `columnNamesMD.get(i)` instead of `tableNamesMD.get(i)`.

Comment: You should probably  iterate on the nested ArrayList - columnNamesMD. tableNamesMD is not nested

Comment: Your tableNamesMD is an arraylist of strings, therefore if you use get(i).size(), you are trying to get the size of a String at position i. What you might want to check in your second for loop is the columnNamesMD list

Answer (score 2):

In your other loop, you iterate over the elements of `tableNamesMD`, which are all `String` instances. When you get the `i`-th `String`, invoking `size()` raises a compile-time error.

Probably you meant:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tableNamesMD.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(tableNamesMD.get(i));

    for(int j = 0; j < columnNamesMD.get(i).size(); j++) {
        //do stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to iterate all the tables, and for each of the tables iterate its columns, also, I assume that the columns of table `tableNamesMD.get(i)` are `columnNamesMD.get(i)`, in that case Kostantin's answer would work.

But, I think the design is naturally flawed. Since, quite naturally, we want to iterate all the tables and handle some data that's associated to each table, we should do this association in an object oriented manner, i.e:

```
public interface Table {
    String getName();
    List<Column> getColumns();
}

public interface Column {
    String getName();
}
```

And then the iteration code would look like

```
List<Table> tables = ...;
for (Table table : tables) {
    System.out.println(table.getName());
    for (Column column : columns) {
        System.out.println(column.getName());
    }
}
```

We eliminated the association between a table and its columns via a list index, as well as replacing the for with a foreach statement. Both of these changes go a long way in increasing readability of the code, which has a lot of desirable side effects.

Also note that we can rewrite this using stream API like this

```
tables.forEach(table -> {
    System.out.println(table.getName());
    table.getColumns().forEach(column -> System.out.println(column.getName()));
});
```

In general, I would say that if something is thought of as an entity in object oriented programming, then it should be a class.